# UITextView is set to empty and doesn't get updated when coming back to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextview, segue

Lets say I have two UIViewControllers: **view1** and **view2**.

**view1** is the first(main) viewController of a TabBarController and there is a button **B1** that triggers the transition to **view2**. I have a UITextView in **view1** (called **textView**) which gets updated several times using the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 self.textView.text = self.textView.text + "some value"
}
```

When I go to **view2** using button **B1**, still background processes are running for **view1** and they try to update the **textView** using the above code but we are in **view2** and text update can not happen. As the result when I get back to **view1**, the **textview** becomes empty and doesn't get updated anymore. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

In other words, some network communications are running frequently in **view1** and they update the **textview**. It is working as long as I am in **view1**. But when I go to the second viewController (**view2**) and get back to the **view1** (using **Segue**), **textview** becomes empty and never gets updated even though the previous background processes were running and trying to update the text when I was in **view2** (So my problem is that they are trying to update the first object of textView and not the second one, I guess?)

Comment: Put the code of  `textView` update, where from you update the text view.

Answer (score 0):

Add method consisting of above code or the above code itself in **viewWillAppear** Method of view1(VC)

i.e.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.textView.text = self.textView.text + "some value"
        }
    }
```

or

```
func someMethod() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.textView.text = self.textView.text + "some value"
        }
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        someMethod()
    }
```